# Flask SQLAlchemy + Marshal_list_with + selected columns

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to pull down selected columns from joining two tables and returning the results using `api.marshal_list_with`. My model definition is as follows:

```
project_model = api.model('Project', {
'id': fields.String(readOnly=True, description='Unique project id'),
'name': fields.String(required=True, description='Project name'),
'created_user_id': fields.String(description='Id for user that created the project'),
'created_time': fields.String(readOnly=True, description='Time of first creation'),
'updated_time': fields.String(description='Time of last modification'),
'access_type': fields.String(description='Level of access')})
```

The actual request code is:

```
@api.marshal_list_with(project_model)
def get(self):
    """
    Get details of all projects associated with user
    """
    user_id = get_jwt_identity()
    projects_l = db.session.query(Project, ProjectUserJunction).join(
        ProjectUserJunction).filter(ProjectUserJunction.user_id == user_id).values(
        Project.id, Project.name, Project.created_user_id,
        Project.created_time, Project.updated_time,
        ProjectUserJunction.access_type)
    return projects_l
```

When I make the get call though, the response I get is a bunch of nulls:

```
{
    "id": null,
    "name": null,
    "created_user_id": null,
    "created_time": null,
    "updated_time": null,
    "access_type": null
}
```

If I print out the contents of `project_l` on the server, it's not blanks, so I know that the query is not broken. It may just be something with marshaling that I am missing. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess casting qs to list, should do the trick.